# Kernel Density Estimation on an image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a set of points [x1,y1][x2,y2]...[xn,yn]. I need to display them using the kernel density Estimation in a 2D image. How to perform this? I was referring the following code and it's bit confusing. Looking for a simple explanation.

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html

```
img = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
circles_xy =[[524,290][234,180]...[432,30]]

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=1.0, kernel='gaussian')
kde.fit(circles_xy)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would continue on the same path by drawing the contours of the PDF of the kernel density estimate. However, this might not give the information you need, because the values of the PDF are not very informative. Instead, I would rather compute the minimum *volume level set*. From a given probability level, the minimum level set is the domain containing that fraction of the distribution. If we consider a domain defined by a given value of the PDF, this must correspond to an unknown PDF value. The problem of finding this PDF value is done by inversion.

Based on a given sample, the natural idea is to compute an approximate distribution based on kernel smoothing, just like you did. Then, for any distribution in [OpenTURNS](https://openturns.org), the `computeMinimumVolumeLevelSetWithThreshold` method computes the required level set and the corresponding PDF value.

Let's see how it goes in practice. In order to get an interesting example, I create a 2D distribution from a mixture of two gaussian distributions.

```
import openturns as ot
# Create a gaussian
corr = ot.CorrelationMatrix(2)
corr[0, 1] = 0.2
copula = ot.NormalCopula(corr)
x1 = ot.Normal(-1., 1)
x2 = ot.Normal(2, 1)
x_funk = ot.ComposedDistribution([x1, x2], copula)

# Create a second gaussian
x1 = ot.Normal(1.,1)
x2 = ot.Normal(-2,1)
x_punk = ot.ComposedDistribution([x1, x2], copula)

# Mix the distributions
mixture = ot.Mixture([x_funk, x_punk], [0.5,1.])

# Generate the sample
sample = mixture.getSample(500)
```

This is where your problem starts. Creating the bivariate kernel smoothing from multidimensional Scott's rule only requires two lines.

```
factory = ot.KernelSmoothing()
distribution = factory.build(sample)
```

It would be straightforward just to plot the contours of this estimated distribution.

```
distribution.drawPDF()
```

produces:

[image: Contours of the PDF of the 2D KDE]

This shows the shape of the distribution. However, the contours of the PDF do not convey much information on the initial sample.

The inversion to compute the minimum volume level set requires an initial sample which is generated from Monte-Carlo method when the dimension is greater than 1. The default sample size (close to 16 000) is OK, but I usually set it up by myself just to make sure that I understand what I do.

```
ot.ResourceMap.SetAsUnsignedInteger(
    "Distribution-MinimumVolumeLevelSetSamplingSize", 1000
)
alpha = 0.9
levelSet, threshold = distribution.computeMinimumVolumeLevelSetWithThreshold(alpha)
```

The `threshold` variable contains the solution of the problem, i.e. the PDF value which corresponds to the minimum volume level set.

The final step is to plot the sample and the corresponding minimum volume level set.

```
def drawLevelSetContour2D(
    distribution, numberOfPointsInXAxis, alpha, threshold, sample
):
    """
    Compute the minimum volume LevelSet of measure equal to alpha and get the
    corresponding density value (named threshold).
    Draw a contour plot for the distribution, where the PDF is equal to threshold.
    """
    sampleSize = sample.getSize()
    X1min = sample[:, 0].getMin()[0]
    X1max = sample[:, 0].getMax()[0]
    X2min = sample[:, 1].getMin()[0]
    X2max = sample[:, 1].getMax()[0]
    xx = ot.Box([numberOfPointsInXAxis], ot.Interval([X1min], [X1max])).generate()
    yy = ot.Box([numberOfPointsInXAxis], ot.Interval([X2min], [X2max])).generate()
    xy = ot.Box(
        [numberOfPointsInXAxis, numberOfPointsInXAxis],
        ot.Interval([X1min, X2min], [X1max, X2max]),
    ).generate()
    data = distribution.computePDF(xy)
    graph = ot.Graph("", "X1", "X2", True, "topright")
    labels = ["%.2f%%" % (100 * alpha)]
    contour = ot.Contour(xx, yy, data, ot.Point([threshold]), ot.Description(labels))
    contour.setColor("black")
    graph.setTitle(
        "%.2f%% of the distribution, sample size = %d" % (100 * alpha, sampleSize)
    )
    graph.add(contour)
    cloud = ot.Cloud(sample)
    graph.add(cloud)
    return graph
```

We finally plot the contours of the level set with 50 points in each axis.

```
numberOfPointsInXAxis = 50
drawLevelSetContour2D(mixture, numberOfPointsInXAxis, alpha, threshold, sample)
```

The following figure plots the sample along with the contour of the domain which contains 90% of the population estimated from the kernel smoothing distribution. Any point outside of this region can be considered as an outlier, although we might use the higher alpha=0.95 value for this purpose.

[image: High density region of the sample]

The full example is detailed in [Minimum volume level set](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/examples/probabilistic_modeling/minimum_volume_level_set_2D.html). An application of this to stochastic processes is done in [othdrplot](https://github.com/mbaudin47/othdrplot). The ideas used here are detailed in : Rob J Hyndman and Han Lin Shang. Rainbow plots , bagplots and boxplots for functional data. Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 19:29-45, 2009.